# Python - dictionaries and making a list of student enrollments

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm new at Python and I have to make a list of student enrollments and use dictionaries within a class.

I want to manage a list of exam enrollments. To do this, it is necessary to create the Enrollment class: these objects are characterized by a code (of the course), a date, the name of the course, student id and the date of the exam. Then create a Python class called  ListOfEnrollments, which uses a dictionary to represent the list. The class provides the following methods: addEnrollment (which receives the fields describing the enrollment to be entered), get (which receives the code of the enrollment to be returned and returns a dictionary containing the enrollment sought), drop (which receives the code of the enrollment to be deleted from the collection) and toJSON (which returns a string obtained by serializing the internal dictionary

Here is what I have done:

```
import json

class Enrollment: 

    def __init__ (self, code, date, course, studentId, dateOfExam): 
        self.code=code
        self.date= date
        self.course = course
        self.studentId = studentId
        self.dateOfExam = dateOfExam

class ListOfEnrollments(dict):

    def __addEnrollment__(self, code, date, course, studentId, dateOfExam):
        return Enrollment

    def __getEnrollment__(self, code, date, course, studentId, dateOfExam):
        return self.__dict__[Enrollment]

    def __delitem__(self, code)
        del self.__dict__[code]

json_object = json.loads(enrollment_string)
```

so i wanted to know if it makes sense or if i could improve something, as I was in doubt of how to implement a dictionary within a class and combine it with json

thanks in advance

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the shown code. (2) Don't create your own names with double underscore at beginning and end. (3) If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code (and a specific question).

Comment: In class ListOfEnrollments, why are you inheriting from the dict class rather than simply instantiating a dictionary in its constructor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This might be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/